# A value for the covariate “x” must be provided (as an argument to effectfun)

Tags: spatstat

I am reading text from spatstat textbook, and trying to learn model fit using ppm. 
I created a model with carteisan coordinates as the covariates. And then I wanted to see the effect of only one covariate on the model,

`model1 = ppm(chicago_ppp ~ x+y)
plot(effectfun(model1, covname = "x"))`

but I get the error

`Error in effectfun(model1, covname = "x") : A value for the covariate “y” must be provided (as an argument to effect fun)`

The same happens if I use covname "y" it asks for "x"

Can someone please show me what is my mistake. Thank you.

UPDATE: When I use only one covariate, and I use effectfun with that one covariate, there is no error. When I use two covariates and I want to check effectfun of one covariate, I get this error in the question.

Comment: Please remember to make your code sample reproducible, so it is easy to copy paste into an R session. You haven't defined `chicago_ppp`, and you might as well use some built in dataset from `spatstat` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to calculate the estimated intensity for different values of
`x` you need to fix a value for `y` like this:

```r
    library(spatstat)
    model <- ppm(cells ~ x + y)
    plot(effectfun(model, covname = "x", y = 0.1))
```

[image]

```r
    plot(effectfun(model, covname = "x", y = 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.  I will improve my next questions with reproducible code.